# How to add to a BigDecimal

Tags: java

I have the following function that itterates over an array, calls a method on each 'Refund' object that returns a BigDecimal that contains some value e.g. 20.45:

```
private String getTransactionTotals(Refund[] refunds) {

    BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0.00);

    /*
     *  Itterates over all the refund objects and adds
     *  their amount payables together to get a total 
     */
    for ( Refund refund : refunds ) {

        total.add(refund.getAmountPayable());           

    }

    total = total.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
    return total.toString();
}
```

The problem is that it always returns '0.00'. I know for a fact that the array that I'm passing is not null, and the values that their 'getAmountPayable()' function retuns are also not null or equal to 0. I don't know if I've been staring at this for too long and I'm missing the obvious, some help would greatly be appreciated.

PS - 'getAmountPayble()' return a value of type BigDecimal

Comment: You  might want to use the constant [`BigDecimal.ZERO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the return value of `add`, because `BigDecimal` is immutable. So you want:

```
total = total.add(refund.getAmountPayable());
```

(Personally I think this would have been more obvious if the method had been called `plus` rather than `add`, but never mind.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. That was indeed the issue. :)

Comment: @Relborg Accept the answer in that case :)

Comment: @DanTemple Will do, have to wait a few mins though

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet's answer is correct. Here is the API javadoc for [BigDecimal#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add%28java.math.BigDecimal%29):

> > Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this + augend), and whose scale is max(this.scale(), augend.scale()).